# Parsing a user entered Array in JavaScript with Parsimmon

Tags: javascript, string-parsing, parser-combinators

I was looking at how I could parse an array in JavaScript that the user enters, e.g. `'[1, 2, 3, 4, [1, 2, 3], "test", "test hello"]'`. 
Now, I found Parsimmon which seems like a good tool to do so. The library comes with an example of a JSON parser implemented like this:

```
let JSONParser = P.createLanguage({
            // This is the main entry point of the parser: a full JSON value.
            value: r =>
                P.alt(
                    r.object,
                    r.array,
                    r.string,
                    r.number,
                    r.null,
                    r.true,
                    r.false
                ).thru(parser => whitespace.then(parser)),

            // The basic tokens in JSON, with optional whitespace afterward.
            lbrace: () => word("{"),
            rbrace: () => word("}"),
            lbracket: () => word("["),
            rbracket: () => word("]"),
            comma: () => word(","),
            colon: () => word(":"),

            // `.result` is like `.map` but it takes a value instead of a function, and
            // `.always returns the same value.
            null: () => word("null").result(null),
            true: () => word("true").result(true),
            false: () => word("false").result(false),

            // Regexp based parsers should generally be named for better error reporting.
            string: () =>
                token(P.regexp(/"((?:\\.|.)*?)"/, 1))
                    .map(interpretEscapes)
                    .desc("string"),

            number: () =>
                token(P.regexp(/-?(0|[1-9][0-9]*)([.][0-9]+)?([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?/))
                    .map(Number)
                    .desc("number"),

            // Array parsing is just ignoring brackets and commas and parsing as many nested
            // JSON documents as possible. Notice that we're using the parser `json` we just
            // defined above. Arrays and objects in the JSON grammar are recursive because
            // they can contain any other JSON document within them.
            array: r => r.lbracket.then(r.value.sepBy(r.comma)).skip(r.rbracket),

            // Object parsing is a little trickier because we have to collect all the key-
            // value pairs in order as length-2 arrays, then manually copy them into an
            // object.
            pair: r => P.seq(r.string.skip(r.colon), r.value),

            object: r =>
                r.lbrace
                    .then(r.pair.sepBy(r.comma))
                    .skip(r.rbrace)
                    .map(pairs => {
                        let object = {};
                        pairs.forEach(pair => {
                            let [key, value] = pair;
                            object[key] = value;
                        });
                        return object;
                    })
        });
```

Now, I tried to implement my own parser for Array without using the createLanguage function, this is my implementation so far:

```
let comma = word2(',');
let lBracket = word2('[');
let rBracket = word2(']');
let arrayParser = P.lazy(
            () =>
                // P.seq(
                lBracket.then(
                    P.alt(
                        P.digits,
                        // stringParser.trim(P.optWhitespace).sepBy(P.string(','))
                        // P.digits.sepBy1(P.string(',')),
                        arrayParser
                    ).thru(parser => P.optWhitespace.then(parser)).sepBy(comma)
                ).skip(
                    rBracket.trim(P.optWhitespace)
                )
            // )
        );
```

The implementation works for parsing the following:

```
'[1, 2, 3, 4]'
```

but not for parsing a nested array:

```
'[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3], 4]'
```

I would like to understand what I am doing wrong if there is anyone willing to answer.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not `JSON.parse`? Your examples are valid JSON. If there are things that are valid JSON that you don't want to allow, it's easy to detect them after the fact.

Comment: Because I might want to change the parser in the future... also JSON.parse will throw an exception in case the user entered something wrong. In contrast, Parsimmon returns an object with a result field of true or false...

Comment: That second issue is a non-issue: Use `try`/`catch`. But it sounds like you're struggling to create a basic parser, which suggests you'd be better off using one that's already created. (There are also JSON parsers [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/) you could tweak, but then, you already have a parser you're tweaking, so that many not be all that helpful...) In any case, good luck!